# Divide by zero encountered in double_scalars

Tags: python, numpy

In python i have a function which calculates an angle theta as follows:

```
def Calc_Theta(x,y):
    if x == 0:
       theta = 0
    else:
       theta = np.arctan(y/x)
    return theta
```

This is a shortened version of the actual code but it gets to the point. 
Now this is the point where it differentiates from other questions i found using google.

I know that for some values of x the theta calculated will return 0, that is why is made a statement to not calculate theta but instead return 0.

The function outputs values as intended so there is no problem there but i still get the warning:

> RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars

How do i get rid of this error since there is no situation where this error could be possible?

Comment: The problem could be elsewhere. How about an MCVE.

Comment: While typing the MCVE i discovered that in my function i used theta elsewhere, though theta was set as 0 the other parts of the function that used theta had to have such an exception as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: As a debugging tip, if you run a script with `python -Werror my_script.py`, warnings are turned into exceptions, so that you get a full traceback when the first warning is encountered.  That often makes it easier to pinpoint the cause of the warning.

Comment: You should be using arctan2 anyway. Your current code treats x=0,y=1 the same as x=0,y=-1

Comment: Thanks for the tip, with using arctan2 i dont need the exceptions :)

Comment: @MarkDickinson I am using IPython notebooks, is there a way to use them in the notebook itself? When i google the -Werror i do not get a great explanation of how to use it. I tried (hoping it would work) using it in the terminal IPython notebooks opens

Comment: Returning 0 introduces a math discontinuity in `Calc_Theta()`.  This will cause problems if a numerical derivative is taken elsewhere in other code utilizing this function\.  Shouldn't you be returning  + or -  π /2 instead when x is near 0?

Comment: @Marlo: Ah, sorry; I don't know what the equivalent is for the IPython notebook.